# Easy way to extract the first k child out of very large xml file (possibly corrupted)

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there an easy way, may be using a *XPath* query (or any other command line tool that can be easily found in every linux/osx machine) to extract from a large XML file a subset of the original file?

Specifically I have a large xml file in the format:

```
<root>
  <header>...<>
  <item name="1">...<>
  <item name="2">...<>
  ...
  <item name="1000000">..<>
</root>
```

and I want in output a smaller XML file with the first k items (say 10) including the header. As a side note, consider that the file might be corrupted. Essentially I am looking for a command similar to `head` that parses the XML file using a SAX parser (in order to be not memory hungry and resilient to premature termination of the file).

Comment: For corrupted files: You would need a **tolerant XML parser** for that. That means, an XML parser who behaves like an HTML parser. Most XML parsers are **STRICT** on their input, meaning the XML file **MUST** be well-formed. Your question indicates that is not the case, therefore normal solutions do probably not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think streaming processing with `xsl:iterate` allows that in XSLT 3.0 as currently implemented by Saxon 9.7 EE (which obviously is not a command line tool easily available on LINUX, but as it does solve the problem I think it its worth mentioning): assuming a not well-formed XML of the name `test2015122701.xml` in the form

```
<root>
  <header>...</header>
  <item name="1">...</item>
  <item name="2">...</item>
  <item name="3">...</item>
  <item name="4">...</item>
  <item>
</root>
```

and an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet with code

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="items-to-copy" as="xs:integer" select="4"/>
<xsl:variable name="children-to-copy" as="xs:integer" select="$items-to-copy + 1"/>

<xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'test2015122701.xml'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="main" match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:stream href="{$input-uri}">
      <xsl:iterate select="root/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() eq $children-to-copy">
          <xsl:break/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:stream>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.7 EE, when run with `java -jar saxon9ee.jar -it:main -xsl:sheet.xsl` produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <header>...</header>
   <item name="1">...</item>
   <item name="2">...</item>
   <item name="3">...</item>
   <item name="4">...</item>
</root>
```

If we run with the `-t` command line option to check some details on processing we see:

```
Streaming file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2015122701.xml
URIResolver.resolve href="test2015122701.xml" base="file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2015122702.xsl"
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Streaming test2015122701.xml : early exit
```

so Saxon indeed processes only the beginning of the file and exits before encountering the not well-formed markup after the first elements.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here is an example using Perl and XML::Twig:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $itemCount = 0;
my $breakCount = 4;

sub count_items {
    my ($t, $item) = @_;
    $itemCount++;
    if ($itemCount == $breakCount) {
      $t->finish_now();
    }
}

my $input = 'input.xml';
my $result = 'output.xml';



my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => { item => \&count_items},
  pretty_print => 'indented'
);

$twig->parsefile($input);
$twig->print_to_file($result);
```

I am afraid I don't know how well Perl and XML::Twig are supported on LINUX, I have tested the above to work using Perl 5.20.3 on Windows with XML::Twig 3.49.